# Access a Parameter from different module in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm new to verilog and I have following question,

```
package pkg;
   parameter WIDTH = 6;
endpackage

module mod1 #(parameter PAR = 10)(in1,clk,out1); 
   import pkg::*;
   localparam FOO = 10; 
   input in1,clk;
   output out1;
   assign out1 = in1;
endmodule
module mod2 (in1,clk,out1);
   logic a1[WIDTH:0];
endmodule
```

I have imported package `pkg` in module `mod1` and can I use parameter `WIDTH` (defined in `pkg`) in module `mod2`as in above code?

I'm trying to understand the scopes of verilog. Can someone please explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. An import statement is only local to the block it appears in. Basically from the point it appears in the source, to the *end* word. In this case, the `endmodule`.